# unpredictable error to draw semicircle in xib tableviewcell

Tags: swift, cashapelayer, cagradientlayer

In the code I am trying to create semicircle using cashapelayer() and uibezierpath() . The cashapelayer and uibezierpath is not drawing the path as specified . In the image the circle should end at the right edge of the screen(self.contentView.frame.width). But not working out

import UIKit

class bottomCommanTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

```
let gradient_cb :CAGradientLayer? = CAGradientLayer()

@IBOutlet weak var sc_1: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var sc_2: UIView!

override func awakeFromNib() {

    super.awakeFromNib()

    // Initialization code

   
    let path_cb = UIBezierPath()

    let z0 = CGPoint(x: 0  , y: sc_1.bounds.size.height )

    let z2 = CGPoint(x: (self.bounds.size.width)/2, y: -self.bounds.size.height )

    

    let z1 = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width, y: self.bounds.size.height)

    path_cb.move(to: z1)

    path_cb.addQuadCurve(to: z0, controlPoint: z2)
    path_cb.lineWidth = 1

    path_cb.stroke()

    let line_cb = CAShapeLayer()

    line_cb.path = path_cb.cgPath;

    line_cb.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

    line_cb.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

    

    gradient_cb!.colors = [UIColor().HexToColor_2(hexString: "#DB9240", alpha: 1.0).cgColor,

                          UIColor().HexToColor_2(hexString: "#F14E6B", alpha: 1.0).cgColor]

    gradient_cb!.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)

    gradient_cb!.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)

    gradient_cb!.mask = line_cb

    self.layer.addSublayer(gradient_cb!)


}

override func layoutSublayers(of layer: CALayer) {

    super.layoutSublayers(of: layer)

    if let layer = gradient_cb {

        layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)

    }

}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {

    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)



    // Configure the view for the selected state

}
```

}

extension UIColor{

```
func HexToColor_2(hexString: String, alpha:CGFloat? = 1.0) -> UIColor {

    // Convert hex string to an integer

    let hexint = Int(self.intFromHexString(hexStr: hexString))

    let red = CGFloat((hexint & 0xff0000) >> 16) / 255.0

    let green = CGFloat((hexint & 0xff00) >> 8) / 255.0

    let blue = CGFloat((hexint & 0xff) >> 0) / 255.0

    let alpha = alpha!

    // Create color object, specifying alpha as well

    let color = UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)

    return color

}



func intFromHexString_2(hexStr: String) -> UInt32 {

    var hexInt: UInt32 = 0

    // Create scanner

    let scanner: Scanner = Scanner(string: hexStr)

    // Tell scanner to skip the # character

    scanner.charactersToBeSkipped = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: "#") as CharacterSet

    // Scan hex value

    scanner.scanHexInt32(&hexInt)

    return hexInt

}
```

}
[Storyboard image of semicircle[][1]][2]

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YhML.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YhML.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiUfm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
class TCTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var gradient_cb = CAGradientLayer()
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        self.layoutGradientLayer()
    }

    func layoutGradientLayer() {
        gradient_cb.frame = self.bounds
                
        let line_cb = CAShapeLayer()
        line_cb.path = {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size)
            let path = UIBezierPath()
            let z0 = CGPoint(x: 0  , y: self.bounds.size.height )
            let z2 = CGPoint(x: (self.bounds.size.width)/2, y: -self.bounds.size.height )
            let z1 = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width, y: self.bounds.size.height)
            path.move(to: z1)
            path.addQuadCurve(to: z0, controlPoint: z2)
            path.lineWidth = 1
            path.stroke()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            
            return path.cgPath
        }()
        line_cb.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        line_cb.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

        gradient_cb.colors = [UIColor().HexToColor_2(hexString: "#DB9240", alpha: 1.0).cgColor,
                             UIColor().HexToColor_2(hexString: "#F14E6B", alpha: 1.0).cgColor]
        gradient_cb.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
        gradient_cb.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
        gradient_cb.mask = line_cb
        if gradient_cb.superlayer == nil {
            layer.addSublayer(gradient_cb)
        }
    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
    override func layoutSublayers(of layer: CALayer) {
        super.layoutSublayers(of: layer)
        self.layoutGradientLayer()
    }
    
}
```

The demo cell I've just write. After view's layer's frame changed, you need to redraw the layer to adjust the semicircle's radius and the arcCenter.

Comment: Your solution did not work .. it gave the same result I was getting. What could be the problem ??

Comment: Have you tried ```debug view Hierarchy```? I wonder where the ```gradient_cb``` located and how it looked in the view hierarchy

Comment: Paste all the code of the tableViewCell if possible. I need more information to try my luck

Comment: I am new to swift .. could you tell me how shall I do it.

Comment: Just paste the tableViewCell code will do my good. Ignore the ```debug view Hierarchy``` thing. I need your code to write a simple demo myself please.

Comment: The above code which I have shared that's all present in tableview cell nothing more .. and for your info I am doing it in tableview cell xib . Please help asap

Comment: Updated my question with full code of tableview cell ..is that enough ??

Comment: Give me some time please. I'm working. Trust me, thx.

Comment: OK I think I've work out something. Give me some minutes to organize my words.

Comment: I've just edit my answer. In my demo the semicricle is showed correctly. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Thank you for answer . But In my code I have set three points z1, z2 and z3. Where z1 I am going place in negative x axis(left side of screen edge) and z3 will end at the right edge of the screen .. can it be done in your solution??

Comment: I get confused. In your code that's no such thing called z3? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I am sorry ..thats z0, z1 and z2

Comment: Answer edited. I'll just wait until you satisfy and then go to bed.

Comment: Give me 5 min ..I will check

Comment: Huge ..lots of thank you .. it worked .. I had been trying to solve it since yesterday . Your solution worked for ..great .!!!!!

Comment: You are welcome. Vote this answer up and accept this answer if you think it works, thank you.

Comment: Actually .. how to add button on that layer . My button is getting hidden because of it ..

Comment: Bro, accepted this answer. Vote this answer up. And ask another question about what you are facing please.